# Why i cannot use ng-show inside directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make an element that show it's content when clicking on it:
There are many ways to do it. I want to do it inside directive.
Why is it not working?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y13bcD7Ikuk6pERM9Mm8?p=preview

HTML:

```
<ez-option title="option 1">
        Option 1 inside
        <input ng-model="x">{{x}}
    </ez-option>
    <ez-option title="option 2">
        Option 2 inside
   </ez-option>
```

JavaScript:

```
directive('ezOption',function(){
    return {
        template:'<li></li><div ng-show=selected ng-transclude class=body></div>',
        link:function ($scope,iElement,iAttrs,controller,tanscludeFn){
            iElement.find('li').html(iAttrs.title)
            iElement.find('li').on('click',function(){
              $scope.selected=true
            })
        },
        scope:true,
        transclude:true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your event is outside of angular ...it is a DOM event, you need to tell angular about the scope changes so it can run a digest.

Use `$scope.$apply()`. If you use core event directives like `ng-click` this is done internally by angular.

```
   iElement.find('li').on('click',function(){
        $scope.selected=true;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

Thus you are generally better off using the multitude of core angular event directives before resorting to your own

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IiMYiidcMogP0wQvJfxS?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

This is because angular is not aware of the change in scope from your click event. To make it aware, you should do this

```
            iElement.find('li').on('click',function(){
              $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.selected=true;
              })
            })
```

Alternatively, you can use angular's `ng-click` instead

```
m.directive('ezOption',function(){
    return {
        template:'<li ng-click="selected=true"></li><div ng-show=selected ng-transclude class=body></div>',
        link:function ($scope,iElement,iAttrs,controller,tanscludeFn){
            iElement.find('li').html(iAttrs.title);
        },
        controller:function($scope){
          $scope.selected=false
        },
        transclude:true
    }
})
```